# Where does the Flex compiler put the .aso files?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I want to be able to hand delete the intermediate .aso files generated by the Flex mxmlc compiler.  Where are they stored?

(I know the Flash IDE has a "delete asos" button, but I'm using the FlashDevelop IDE, which doesn't.  The reason I want this is so I can play around with the compiler's warning settings on a fairly large project, and the compiler won't try to recompile if the .aso files are up to date.)

Thanks, Matt

Update:  Thanks, indeed Filemon turned up no .aso files, or any other intermediate file I could see. Touching each file is what I wound up doing. So my new question is: how heck *does* mxmlc store it's intermediate files? It must have them because deleting the .swf doesn't trigger a full recompile.

Comment: Thanks, Filemon turned up no .aso files, or any other intermediate file I could see.

Touching each file is what I wound up doing.  

So my new question is: how heck *does* mxmlc store it's intermediate files?  It must have them because deleting the .swf doesn't trigger a full recompile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASO are AS2-specific (and BTW FlashDevelop selectively cleans ASO files automatically).

For AS3, FlashDevelop hosts the Flex Compiler SHell (FCSH) which is included in the Flex 3 SDK. This nice tool keeps your code compiled in memory and it should recompile the classes which have changed.

In FlashDevelop, if the compiler plays dumb, you can just switch the active project - this will reset the shell.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the Flex 3 compilers do not use .aso files since these are only created for ActionScript 2 classes. I don't know FlashDevelop enough but I would expect that it rebuilds the app if you change the compiler settings. If it doesn't, perhaps making a small change to a source file (adding a space) so the IDE will recompile will do the trick.

Comment: Merely touch-ing the file should be enough to make the project recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx).  It is very useful for figuring out where files are coming from or going to (among other things).